# Highlight candle which is near to moving average on pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to identify whether a candle is near the moving average(not touching the MA). The candle that touching the moving average is working perfectly. How can I highlight the candle which is near to the MA?

Here is my current code

```
sma20 = sma(close, 20)
bullishEC = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[1]
maLongCondition = close > sma20 and (cross(sma20,low) or cross(sma20,close))
buy = bullishEC and maLongCondition
barcolor( buy ? color.yellow : na, title="bullish")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the desired area with sma20 value + your desired percentage:

```
colorAreaPercentage = input(1 , "Colored area precentage" , input.integer , minval = 0)
sma20 = sma(close, 20)
barColor =  close > sma20 and close < sma20 + (sma20 * colorAreaPercentage /100) ? color.fuchsia : close < sma20 and close > sma20 - (sma20 * colorAreaPercentage / 100) ? color.orange : na
if ((high >= sma20 and low <= sma20) or high == sma20 or low == sma20)
    barColor := na
barcolor(barColor)
```

This will color 1% above the moving average and 1% below the moving average

Edit:

```
if ((high >= sma20 and low <= sma20) or high == sma20 or low == sma20)
    barColor := na
```

This part of code will leave the touching candles uncolored.

Comment: Hey Behnam, It works! I changed the percentage to float to get a little more accurate result. Many thanks